# ''Install Prohibited" iphone SDK

Tags: iphone

I have upgraded by iphone to 4.1 from 3.1.3 version. I have also upgrded sdk to 4.1 . My application are working fine on simullator. When trying to run it on device im getting 'An unknown error message "install prohibited" was received from the device'. Wher am i going wrong?

Comment: No im not using any private APIs.I get the same error for the all the applications. Even the one i downloaded from apple developer site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try checking restrictions in your device Settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Restrictions on my device was on. Now im able to add applications to my device.

Comment: Which restrictions are you referring to?

Comment: Settings > General > Restrictions > Add Applications

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps double check using XCode's Organiser that your phone is in Development Mode?

Comment: My phone is in Development Mode. I have crested and added Provisioning Profile also.